# Mean.IO - how to implement additional OAuth providers

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

mean.io does a great job of implementing a number of Oauth providers out of the box, unfortunately I want to use Spotify which is not one of them.

Mean.io uses passport which means that it should be as easy as implementing the passport-spotify npm module. However I am having difficulty understanding how mean.io's Oauth comes together. I also am having difficulty finding relevant information on how it works.

I can see that there is a config file in the config folder where the Oauth providers are configured but I can't tell what happens past there.

Is anybody able to point me in the right direction on how to implement an additional OAuth provider with mean.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Strategies
>
> Passport has a comprehensive set of over 140 authentication strategies
>   covering social networking, enterprise integration, API services, and
>   more. The [complete list](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/wiki/Strategies) is available on the wiki.

You might be interested in this one:

https://github.com/JMPerez/passport-spotify

Comment: thank you that pointed me in the right direction and I got it implemented ok.